# How to remove the filename from a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, string

I have strings in my column `FileName` from table `xxx` DB-mySQL

```
P:\exter\Time Sheet\old\old\Sources\Rainbow\WpfModule\obj\x86\Release\Wp-fModule.csproj.sdgfhsd.txt
C:\Users\petro\Desktop\SqlSpatialTools.65021\noname.txt
C:\Users\larik\Desktop\TSQLQuerying20090710\temp\Shi_pp-ers.txt
C:\Users\ziza\Desktop\New folder\jdhl_xhj.txt
```

In the output I need only the file path, without file name, like:

```
P:\exter\Time Sheet\old\old\Sources\Rainbow\WpfModule\obj\x86\Release
C:\Users\petro\Desktop\SqlSpatialTools.65021
C:\Users\larik\Desktop\TSQLQuerying20090710\temp
C:\Users\ziza\Desktop\New folder
```

Comment: And your DB engine is?

Comment: Which dbms? (How to find last \ differs...)

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: which DB is it? MySQL? MSSQL? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-Sql you can write as:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE (filepth), CHARINDEX ('\', REVERSE 
(filepth))+1, LEN (filepth)))
FROM @Test -- your table
```

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you.
check it out

```
declare @a nvarchar(max)= 'c:lkd\kdf\sd5\78j\fgt.txt'

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(@a),  CHARINDEX ('\', reverse(@a))+1, len(@a)))
```